# Create vector grid from canvas using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I've modified "Hex grid from layer bounds" script to my need. Just added `cellsizex` and `cellsizey`. Changed the hexagonal - 3 to "1" to make it as a square grid. Is it possible to include an option to select extent from canvas? Instead of getting it from layer extent, I want to manually select the extents from the canvas by drawing a square or rectangle.

I am new to scripting and though I can understand what a line of code does, I find it difficult to implement it by myself. For eg, with the help of the above said code, I was trying to get the extents from the canvas through a square or rectangle drawing.

What I did was, Create new script -> just started to type (after the initial declaration or whatever) `## get extent`, `##select extent`...things like that.

The problem is, i don't know which will be the right method, what is for what?

Is script editor's code different from python's? (Don't know python either).

What do I have to do to build small scripting tools by myself?

Comment: Where can I find "Hex grid from layer bounds" script?

Comment: In Processing toolbox -> Scripts -> Example scripts

Comment: I meant where the script itself is. It is in `...\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\script\scripts\Hex_grid_from_layer_bounds.py`. Answer to your question is that Yes, it is possible by modifying the script. I can't do it but probably soon someone shows how to take extents from a selected geometry instead of (input.extent().

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's much help out there when it comes to writing scripts for QGIS. Sure, there's a couple of examples such as getting coordinates by clicking on the canvas but in my opinion there's 2 things which could help: learn some Python (there's plenty of info/books etc available); create complex models using the Modeler, save it as Python script and play around with the code. Or you can always ask the lovely people at GIS:SE for help!

Comment: Yep. Bought two books last week, Learning Geospatial Analysis with Python and The Pyqgis Programmer's Guide. Hope, instead of asking questions on scripting sooner or later will reply to a question.